# Flatlist scrolls automatically to the first item

Tags: react-native

```
<FlatList
      data={categoryData}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      pagingEnabled
      bounces={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <HomeTabCategoryItem
          categorySelected={categorySelected}
          setCategorySelected={setCategorySelected}
          item={item}
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
```

This the code that I am using but whenever I try to scroll right it automatically scrolls back to leftmost

Comment: It might be helpful to include a gif of what this looks like, as well as a codepen/gist of your code in action so that the bug can be seen very easily for anyone reviewing this post!

Answer (score 0):

Done...
just remove `pagingEnabled`